# jQuery Module Window Not Working

Tags: jquery

Thank you for looking at my code and question!

I am very new to this so please excuse my lack of knowledge with jQuery!

I am trying to create an "Email Sign Up" window. I'd like it to fade in after a few seconds and dim the background. Then the user would either enter their email or click cancel. Then the module window would disappear, and the page would go back to normal.

I was having trouble creating this from scratch so found something called SimpleModal and I'm using that code.
I got it from this website:
http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/

I can get the window module to appear on the page but that's it. Instead I'd like it to fade in and dim the background.

You can see the full page here:
http://halloweenseattle.com/faq_test.php

Thank you in advance. I really, really appreciate your help. I've spent several hours on this so far this morning!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should do:

```
$("#showBtn").click(function() {
    $("#emailPopup").modal({
        overlayId: 'overlay',
        overlayClose: true,
        onOpen: function (dialog) {
            dialog.overlay.fadeIn('slow', function () {
                dialog.container.slideDown('slow', function () {
                    dialog.data.fadeIn('slow');
                });
            });
    }});
});
$('#cancelBtn').click(function() {
    $.modal.close();
});
```

Here is working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/f9681zL1/2/). Nevermind the huge script, I didn't manage to include plugin to fiddle properly. Basically, you should use `onOpen` callback to do the animations. See callback section in [documentation](http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/), first sample.

**Edit:**

Since you're using jQuery UI, I'd suggest using [dialog plugin](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#animated). It's easier to use and you don't have to include other scripts and css:

```
$( "#emailPopup" ).dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    show: {
        effect: "fade",
        duration: 500
    },
    hide: {
        effect: "fade",
        duration: 500
    }
});
$("#showBtn").click(function() {
    $("#emailPopup").dialog("open");
});
$('#cancelBtn').click(function() {
    $("#emailPopup").dialog("close");
});
```

Here is updated [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/f9681zL1/3/).

Comment: Hi @Ilya! I'm still confused about something. Is there a place where I can write more? This box is confining it to a certain amount of characters. I didn't see where I could reply to you with my code changes..? Thank you!

Comment: @Andrea You can update your question with more details

Comment: I will put my new code in the original box (it has more room in there to insert my code).

Comment: Hi @Ilya Whoops I couldn't get that too work, seemed really complicated to input actual code. But if you go to my original link, you'll see what I did. But nothing happens. It >should< fade in slowly, but the window does NOT appear at all.

Comment: I know, look in browser console - you have several errors there: loading script error and 2 syntax errors.

Comment: Hi @Ilya I'm looking at the code (wasn't sure how to do it in browser console - do you mean View -> Source)?  It looks okay to me. I took out the click event, so it just fades in after the page loads. Unfortunately I do not see any errors?

Comment: @Andrea What browser do you use? In Chrome and FireFox it's called by pressing F12 (developer tools). You have error loading following script: http://halloweenseattle.com/jquery.easyModule.js, and you've added styles to `script` tag, but it should be in `style` tag in `head` section

Comment: Hi @Ilya I use Safari. Thanks, I caught the style vs script! My brain wasn't working for that one!

Comment: @Andrea, I saw that you use jQuery UI, so I've updated my answer to use its built-in capabilities for the issue you have.

Comment: Hi @Ilya I'm trying! I added the new code but I still get an error. you can see the error here: http://halloweenseattle.com/code1.jpg

Comment: Wrap new script in `$(function() { ... });` It can't see your email div

Comment: Hi @Ilya Ok I added that part but it still has an error, not sure what I'm doing wrong...? (thank you by the way for all of your help on this!)

Comment: Now you missed the `$` sign before selector. But this is not the main problem. You load your scripts in incorrect order, first should be jQuery and then jQuery-UI (in `head` section). Could you please accept the answer? Because I provided two solutions for your issue both with working demos. And this is not part of the answer to integrate those solutions to your production site, this is where you should adopt the answer to your specific case. I can't help you further because issues you have are very broad and have nothing to do with the original question and taking too much time, no offends.